# Processing: A simple Button

Tags: if-statement, processing

I've already completed most of this assignment, but the part that has been infuriating me is that once this button is clicked not only does it have to turn green but it has to stay green. I've got it to turn green but keeping it green I just cannot figure out. I feel like I've tried everything. I've used a counter that went up by one everytime the mouse was clicked, and then I made a small loop that initiated when the counter was greater than 0 and placed the green rect over the button. I've tried the mouseReleased method. I'm tearing my hair out here.

```java
void setup() {
  size(600,400);
  background(250);
}
void draw(){
  //if mouse pressed turn green   
 //Checks if cursor is inside of button & turns it green when clicked
  if(mouseX>250 && mouseY>150 && mouseX<350 && mouseY<200 && mousePressed==true){
    fill(42,255,15);
    rect(250,150,100,50);
 }
  //Turns button light grey when cursor is hovered over it.
  else if(mouseX>250 && mouseY>150 && mouseX<350 && mouseY<200){
    fill(175);
    rect(250,150,100,50);
  }
  //Turns button med grey when cursor is outside of button
  else{
    fill(131);
    rect(250,150,100,50);
  } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With minimum adjustments to your code, this is one solution, you use a boolean to flag if the button have being clicked, the thing is that `mousePressed` hold the state mouse's buttons is, so as soon as you release  it, the var will be holding false, so tthe flag to go around:

buggy working example code...

```java
boolean clicked = false;

void setup() {
  size(600, 400);
  background(250);
}
void draw() {
  //if mouse pressed turn green   
  //Checks if cursor is inside of button & turns it green when clicked

  if (mouseX>250 && mouseY>150 && mouseX<350 && mouseY<200) { //if hoover
    if (clicked) {// and  clicked
      fill( 101, 131, 101);// dark green
    }
    else {// not clicked
      fill(131);//darker gray
    }

    if (mousePressed) {// if hover and clicked... change flag
      clicked = !clicked; // toogle boolean state
    }
  }
  else {//not hovering

    if (clicked) { // and clicked
      fill(42, 255, 15);// green
    } 
    else {
      fill(175);//gray
    }
  }
  rect(250, 150, 100, 50);// draw anyway...
}
```

You might also want to check the [mousePressed()](http://www.processing.org/reference/mousePressed_.html) function instead of [mousePressed](http://www.processing.org/reference/mousePressed.html), the field you are using...
But this way it works, not so well tough, you could fix without using the `mousePressed()` but with some extra code... I prefer using the function, an example would be:

```java
boolean clicked = false;

void setup() {
  size(600, 400);
  background(250);
}
void draw() {
  if (mouseX>250 && mouseY>150 && mouseX<350 && mouseY<200) { //if hoover
    if (clicked) {// and  clicked
      fill( 101, 131, 101);// dark green
    }
    else {// not clicked
      fill(131);//darker gray
    }
  }
  else {//not hovering

    if (clicked) { // and clicked
      fill(42, 255, 15);// green
    } 
    else {
      fill(175);//gray
    }
  }
  rect(250, 150, 100, 50);// draw anyway...
}

void mouseReleased() {
  clicked = !clicked;
}
```